# Empty spaces being added in pd.concat

Tags: python, pandas

I have two dataframes-

intermediate_df

[image]

Test_Result

[image]

When I do `pd.concat([Test_Result,intermediate_df],axis=1)` to merge the two columns I get-

[image]

Later half of the dataframe where the intermediate_df ends-

[image]

There are a lot of empty spaces in between. There are no empty spaces in the two dataframes separately but when I do concat Test_Result adds a lot of empty rows in itself. The length is also same. Why is this happening?

intermediate_df

```
{'satisfaction_pred': {0: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 1: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 2: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 3: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 4: 'satisfied', 5: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 6: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 7: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 8: 'satisfied', 9: 'satisfied', 10: 'satisfied', 11: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 12: 'satisfied', 13: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 14: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 15: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 16: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 17: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 18: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 19: 'satisfied'}}
```

Test_Result

```
{'Flight Distance': {1183: 448, 1038: 289, 9220: 3390, 908: 689, 8495: 3754, 1864: 1126, 76: 1190, 4581: 925, 620: 427, 7207: 1371, 8406: 3984, 8430: 628, 5848: 2254, 6211: 209, 3487: 674, 9141: 1065, 2124: 1476, 47: 1522, 6226: 631, 3281: 2486}, 'Inflight wifi service': {1183: 2, 1038: 3, 9220: 1, 908: 3, 8495: 5, 1864: 1, 76: 2, 4581: 3, 620: 4, 7207: 1, 8406: 5, 8430: 2, 5848: 1, 6211: 2, 3487: 0, 9141: 4, 2124: 2, 47: 1, 6226: 3, 3281: 5}, 'Departure/Arrival time convenient': {1183: 4, 1038: 4, 9220: 1, 908: 2, 8495: 5, 1864: 1, 76: 4, 4581: 1, 620: 5, 7207: 1, 8406: 5, 8430: 0, 5848: 1, 6211: 3, 3487: 4, 9141: 4, 2124: 3, 47: 1, 6226: 1, 3281: 5}, 'Ease of Online booking': {1183: 2, 1038: 3, 9220: 1, 908: 3, 8495: 5, 1864: 1, 76: 4, 4581: 3, 620: 5, 7207: 1, 8406: 5, 8430: 2, 5848: 1, 6211: 2, 3487: 1, 9141: 4, 2124: 2, 47: 1, 6226: 3, 3281: 3}, 'Gate location': {1183: 2, 1038: 3, 9220: 1, 908: 4, 8495: 5, 1864: 4, 76: 4, 4581: 4, 620: 5, 7207: 1, 8406: 5, 8430: 1, 5848: 1, 6211: 3, 3487: 2, 9141: 3, 2124: 3, 47: 1, 6226: 3, 3281: 5}, 'Food and drink': {1183: 5, 1038: 3, 9220: 1, 908: 3, 8495: 5, 1864: 1, 76: 1, 4581: 4, 620: 5, 7207: 4, 8406: 5, 8430: 4, 5848: 4, 6211: 4, 3487: 3, 9141: 5, 2124: 1, 47: 1, 6226: 2, 3281: 4}, 'Online boarding': {1183: 4, 1038: 3, 9220: 1, 908: 3, 8495: 4, 1864: 1, 76: 4, 4581: 3, 620: 4, 7207: 5, 8406: 5, 8430: 2, 5848: 5, 6211: 2, 3487: 4, 9141: 4, 2124: 2, 47: 1, 6226: 3, 3281: 4}, 'Seat comfort': {1183: 5, 1038: 3, 9220: 1, 908: 3, 8495: 4, 1864: 1, 76: 3, 4581: 4, 620: 1, 7207: 4, 8406: 5, 8430: 4, 5848: 5, 6211: 4, 3487: 4, 9141: 5, 2124: 1, 47: 1, 6226: 2, 3281: 4}, 'Inflight entertainment': {1183: 1, 1038: 3, 9220: 1, 908: 3, 8495: 4, 1864: 1, 76: 2, 4581: 4, 620: 4, 7207: 3, 8406: 5, 8430: 4, 5848: 4, 6211: 4, 3487: 1, 9141: 5, 2124: 1, 47: 1, 6226: 2, 3281: 2}, 'On-board service': {1183: 1, 1038: 5, 9220: 1, 908: 4, 8495: 4, 1864: 5, 76: 2, 4581: 4, 620: 4, 7207: 3, 8406: 4, 8430: 3, 5848: 4, 6211: 1, 3487: 1, 9141: 3, 2124: 4, 47: 3, 6226: 3, 3281: 2}, 'Leg room service': {1183: 2, 1038: 4, 9220: 2, 908: 2, 8495: 4, 1864: 5, 76: 2, 4581: 2, 620: 4, 7207: 4, 8406: 3, 8430: 2, 5848: 4, 6211: 5, 3487: 1, 9141: 4, 2124: 2, 47: 5, 6226: 2, 3281: 2}, 'Baggage handling': {1183: 1, 1038: 4, 9220: 4, 908: 4, 8495: 4, 1864: 5, 76: 2, 4581: 3, 620: 4, 7207: 3, 8406: 5, 8430: 1, 5848: 4, 6211: 4, 3487: 1, 9141: 3, 2124: 3, 47: 3, 6226: 3, 3281: 2}, 'Checkin service': {1183: 4, 1038: 4, 9220: 4, 908: 2, 8495: 4, 1864: 3, 76: 1, 4581: 1, 620: 4, 7207: 3, 8406: 5, 8430: 1, 5848: 3, 6211: 3, 3487: 4, 9141: 1, 2124: 2, 47: 1, 6226: 4, 3281: 4}, 'Inflight service': {1183: 1, 1038: 4, 9220: 3, 908: 4, 8495: 4, 1864: 5, 76: 2, 4581: 3, 620: 4, 7207: 3, 8406: 2, 8430: 2, 5848: 4, 6211: 3, 3487: 1, 9141: 4, 2124: 3, 47: 4, 6226: 4, 3281: 2}, 'Cleanliness': {1183: 3, 1038: 3, 9220: 1, 908: 3, 8495: 4, 1864: 1, 76: 4, 4581: 4, 620: 1, 7207: 5, 8406: 5, 8430: 4, 5848: 3, 6211: 4, 3487: 5, 9141: 5, 2124: 1, 47: 1, 6226: 2, 3281: 4}, 'Departure Delay in Minutes': {1183: 0, 1038: 0, 9220: 0, 908: 0, 8495: 12, 1864: 13, 76: 0, 4581: 0, 620: 38, 7207: 13, 8406: 8, 8430: 8, 5848: 67, 6211: 0, 3487: 0, 9141: 31, 2124: 0, 47: 0, 6226: 0, 3281: 0}, 'Arrival Delay in Minutes': {1183: 0.0, 1038: 0.0, 9220: 0.0, 908: 0.0, 8495: 9.0, 1864: 5.0, 76: 6.0, 4581: 19.0, 620: 23.0, 7207: 23.0, 8406: 8.0, 8430: 0.0, 5848: 58.0, 6211: 25.0, 3487: 0.0, 9141: 33.0, 2124: 0.0, 47: 0.0, 6226: 0.0, 3281: 0.0}, 'id': {1183: 103464, 1038: 105204, 9220: 103033, 908: 93708, 8495: 2014, 1864: 67573, 76: 85018, 4581: 2368, 620: 24065, 7207: 103310, 8406: 53173, 8430: 30563, 5848: 115099, 6211: 50884, 3487: 23344, 9141: 35850, 2124: 30989, 47: 81983, 6226: 65370, 3281: 62750}, 'Age': {1183: 53, 1038: 46, 9220: 32, 908: 27, 8495: 51, 1864: 36, 76: 52, 4581: 12, 620: 50, 7207: 35, 8406: 25, 8430: 51, 5848: 51, 6211: 22, 3487: 61, 9141: 27, 2124: 39, 47: 13, 6226: 34, 3281: 42}, 'Gender_Female': {1183: 1, 1038: 0, 9220: 0, 908: 0, 8495: 1, 1864: 0, 76: 0, 4581: 0, 620: 1, 7207: 0, 8406: 1, 8430: 0, 5848: 1, 6211: 0, 3487: 1, 9141: 1, 2124: 1, 47: 1, 6226: 1, 3281: 0}, 'Gender_Male': {1183: 0, 1038: 1, 9220: 1, 908: 1, 8495: 0, 1864: 1, 76: 1, 4581: 1, 620: 0, 7207: 1, 8406: 0, 8430: 1, 5848: 0, 6211: 1, 3487: 0, 9141: 0, 2124: 0, 47: 0, 6226: 0, 3281: 1}, 'Customer Type_Loyal Customer': {1183: 1, 1038: 1, 9220: 1, 908: 1, 8495: 1, 1864: 0, 76: 1, 4581: 1, 620: 1, 7207: 1, 8406: 1, 8430: 0, 5848: 1, 6211: 1, 3487: 1, 9141: 0, 2124: 1, 47: 1, 6226: 0, 3281: 1}, 'Customer Type_disloyal Customer': {1183: 0, 1038: 0, 9220: 0, 908: 0, 8495: 0, 1864: 1, 76: 0, 4581: 0, 620: 0, 7207: 0, 8406: 0, 8430: 1, 5848: 0, 6211: 0, 3487: 0, 9141: 1, 2124: 0, 47: 0, 6226: 1, 3281: 0}, 'Type of Travel_Business travel': {1183: 0, 1038: 0, 9220: 1, 908: 0, 8495: 1, 1864: 1, 76: 1, 4581: 0, 620: 1, 7207: 1, 8406: 1, 8430: 1, 5848: 1, 6211: 0, 3487: 0, 9141: 1, 2124: 0, 47: 1, 6226: 1, 3281: 1}, 'Type of Travel_Personal Travel': {1183: 1, 1038: 1, 9220: 0, 908: 1, 8495: 0, 1864: 0, 76: 0, 4581: 1, 620: 0, 7207: 0, 8406: 0, 8430: 0, 5848: 0, 6211: 1, 3487: 1, 9141: 0, 2124: 1, 47: 0, 6226: 0, 3281: 0}, 'Class_Business': {1183: 0, 1038: 0, 9220: 1, 908: 0, 8495: 1, 1864: 1, 76: 1, 4581: 0, 620: 0, 7207: 1, 8406: 1, 8430: 0, 5848: 1, 6211: 0, 3487: 0, 9141: 0, 2124: 0, 47: 1, 6226: 0, 3281: 1}, 'Class_Eco': {1183: 1, 1038: 0, 9220: 0, 908: 1, 8495: 0, 1864: 0, 76: 0, 4581: 1, 620: 0, 7207: 0, 8406: 0, 8430: 1, 5848: 0, 6211: 1, 3487: 1, 9141: 1, 2124: 0, 47: 0, 6226: 1, 3281: 0}, 'Class_Eco Plus': {1183: 0, 1038: 1, 9220: 0, 908: 0, 8495: 0, 1864: 0, 76: 0, 4581: 0, 620: 1, 7207: 0, 8406: 0, 8430: 0, 5848: 0, 6211: 0, 3487: 0, 9141: 0, 2124: 1, 47: 0, 6226: 0, 3281: 0}, 'satisfaction': {1183: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 1038: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 9220: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 908: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 8495: 'satisfied', 1864: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 76: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 4581: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 620: 'satisfied', 7207: 'satisfied', 8406: 'satisfied', 8430: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 5848: 'satisfied', 6211: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 3487: 'satisfied', 9141: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 2124: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 47: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 6226: 'neutral or dissatisfied', 3281: 'satisfied'}}
```

Comment: Can you share the code?

Comment: @RishabhBohra the code is just concat of two dataframes which I have shared in the question

Comment: It is mentioned Train_Result in the image name, but Test_Result in the code, please check is that correct

Comment: @ubuntu_noob , please copy and paste both datasets into stack overflow as cod. Alternatively, do `intermediate_df.iloc[0:20].to_dict()` and paste that in your question. Same with the other dataframe.

Comment: the indices of the two dataframes might not be matching. Try `pd.concat([Test_Result,intermediate_df],axis=1, ignore_index=True)`

Comment: @DavidErickson I added

Comment: @YatiRaj Its not working with that.